# Is there an imperative language with a Haskell-like type system?

Tags: object-oriented, programming-languages, haskell, type-systems

I've tried to learn Haskell a few times over the last few years, and, maybe because I know mainly scripting languages, the functional-ness of it has always bothered me (monads seem like a huge mess for doing lots of I/O). However, I think it's type system is *perfect*.

Reading through a guide to Haskell's types and typeclasses (like [this](http://learnyouahaskell.com/types-and-typeclasses)), I don't really see a reason why they would require a functional language, and furthermore, they seem like they would be perfect for an industry-grade object-oriented language (like Java). This all begs the question: **has anyone ever taken Haskell's typing system and made a imperative, OOP language with it?**

If so, I want to use it.

Comment: Somebody's got to say it: **Monads have nothing to do with IO in concept** (it's merely an implementation detail that Haskell chose to use them to model its own IO. Monads also model lists and Option types in that language).

Comment: Scala is probably the closest you're going to get in a semi-mainstream language that is not strongly functional.

Comment: 1) what is perfect about it?  compared to e.g. agda?
2) [history of type classes](http://ipaper.googlecode.com/git-history/243b02cb56424d9e3931361122c5aa1c4bdcbbbd/Typeclasses/type-class-explorationi.pdf);
3) [type inference & subtyping](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/212974/39685), also [here](http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/1afb5x/xpost_from_rhaskell_simon_peyton_jones_on/);
4) [effects systems](http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/4768) -- i.e. do effects have to be explicit?  in the type? etc.

Comment: Check out [Mythryl](http://mythryl.org/)

Comment: you can do strict imperative OO with Haskell: [ekmett/structs](https://github.com/ekmett/structs)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depends on your definition of OOP, which of course is different from everyone else's. But for whatever it's worth, Standard ML has a module system that is more powerful than Haskell's - in Haskell you can only instantiate a type class once, whereas in SML I can order the integers by their traditional ordering, or by divisibility, or any number of other ways I like. SML isn't object-oriented, in the sense that it doesn't have built-in syntax sugar for objects, but it can still be done. But it's not purely functional either - it won't force you to separate side effects from pure code if you don't want to. OCaml and F# are SML dialects that do have an object system. F# in particular may interest you since it runs on .NET and interoperates with C#.

There's also Scala, which is more "industry-grade object-oriented language" and less SML-like, but still has features from SML-like languages like pattern matching and algebraic data types, and interoperates with Java. You might also be interested in Go, which is the language I'm least familiar with but if I recall correctly has structural subtyping (i.e. you don't declare interfaces up front, having the right interfaces is sufficient) like Standard ML's module system.

Comment: Like Telastyn commented, I think Scala is the closest to what I'm describing, but it's a shame that it can't do as much type inference across programs as Haskell can.

Comment: @Graham, most of the places Scala can't infer types are a good idea to make explicit in Haskell anyway.  You'll find it's not a huge sacrifice.

Comment: For all practical purposes, most definitions of OOP are pretty much the same (it's closer to 5 than 5 million different ones), but may be implemented differently.

Comment: @JeffO It was mostly said in jest, but 5 definitions is still 4 too many if you ask me.

Comment: I think comparing the type systems of haskell and F# is unfair though. F# doesn't even come close to the power of higher-kinded polymorphism or type classes etc. they have some neat tricks of their own, sure, but I'm fairly confident in saying that haskell has a WAY more powerful type system.

Comment: also, in haskell you can have different type class instances for the same type by using `newtype` aliasing. it's a bit extra typing and can be a bit cumbersome, but it has exactly 0 runtime overhead at least. thought that's worth pointing out.